# How to Map Entity Navigation Property to Dto

Tags: automapper, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to map the navigation property of an Entity to a DTO without defining each property with the ForMember method.

```
public class OuterSource
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public InnerSource Inner { get; set; }
}

public class InnerSource
{
    public int OtherValue { get; set; }
}

public class OuterDestDto
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public InnerDest Inner { get; set; }
}

public class InnerDestDto
{
    public int OtherValue { get; set; }
}

cfg.CreateMap<OuterSource, OuterDest>();
cfg.CreateMap<InnerSource, InnerDest>();
```

Sp what I want to do is map **OuterSource Entity** to the **InnerDestination Dto** like so:

```
cfg.CreateMap<OuterSource, InnerDest>();
```

I already have the Outer and Inner Objects mapped to eachother. And I tried:

```
cfg.CreateMap<OuterSource, InnerDest>().IncludeMembers(s => s.InnerSource);
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Comment: That gets me a little close. I rewrote the question to better understand my cunundrum. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems to me like you don't need any flattening. Your objects just match.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Not sure why, but seems like they need something like `.MapFrom(src => src.Inner)` which doesn't exist currently and can't be simulated with the existing methods, except eventually `ConstructUsing((src, context) => context.Mapper.Map<InnerDestDto>(src.Inner))`, but that most likely won't play well with projections.

Comment: @axelrotter Can you give us some clue about usage case of the desired mapping?

Comment: I am going to solve this by calling the desired Entity from the Repo with the FK and mapping the resulting OuterSource to the OuterDestination which is probably the wanted functionality.